# Regular expression to extract data from log file

Tags: c#, regex

I can't seem to wrap my head around writing a regular expression for what I'm searching for.

Here's what I have...I have a logfile, within that logfile every so often are lines like this

```
        [Feb 14 15:43:23 UTC] RC5-72: Summary: 6 packets (6.00 stats units)
                              0.00:18:08.40 - [23.68 Mkeys/s]
```

There is a carriage return, line feed at the end of the summary line.

I would like to search for the word "Summary" and then extract "23.68 Mkeys/s" out of it.

I'm trying to do this in C#.

Comment: Jason why don't you use the `IndexOf() method method in C#

Comment: @user2175120: You should add the section of code you have so far with RegEx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mkeys = Regex.Match(logLine, @"Summary[^\[]+\[(?<mkeys>[^\]]+\]").Groups["mkeys"].Value
```

**mkeys**  will contain string between **[** and **]**

Answer (score 0):

off the top of my head:  `Summary(.*)?[(?<mkeys>.*?)\sMkeys`

Comment: How does this account for the line feed?

Comment: Who cares about the line feed.

Comment: I suppose the OP does:  "There is a carriage return, __line feed__ at the end of the summary line."

Comment: Which is totally irrelevant to the goal of **I would like to search for the word "Summary" and then extract "23.68 Mkeys/s" out of it.**

Comment: entirely possible.  But as another answer has been accepted I wouldn't worry about it overly much.